# Default content across nested layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

I have a base layout, BaseLayout.cshtml:

```
<html>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <div id="footer">
        @if (!IsSectionDefined("Footer")) {
            Default footer markup
        }
        else {
            @RenderSection("Footer")
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I derive a nested layout from this, WithSidebar.cshtml:

```
@{ Layout = "BaseLayout.cshtml"; }

<div>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div>Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

What changes need to be done to the WithSidebar layout:

1. To enable the Footer section in BaseLayout to be overridden in a View?
2. Not override the default Footer and stick with the one defined in BaseLayout?

I am developing against ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2. I have read this entry by Marcin Dobosz: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/08/optional-razor-sections-with-default-content.aspx but I don't it works cleanly across nested layouts.

Comment: This question got duplicated over at http://forums.asp.net/t/1632953.aspx

Comment: I am sorry. I had just added a URL to this page originally. A moderator must have copied the question across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original technique requires some extra functionality. I've written a [new post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/15/Razor-Nested-Layouts-and-Redefined-Sections.aspx) that solves the issue:

Comment: Thanks for the detailed blog post Marcin :) And the explanation...

I wonder if we could avoid the 'this' requirement by adding it implicitly (during parsing) in the Razor engine?

I would also continue to work on existing helpers (Html, Url, etc.) Some heuristics would be required in edge cases. But would result in a cleaner syntax:

@RedefineSection(....)

instead of:

@this.RedefineSection(...)

Also: what is the need to pass in a 'private static readonly object _o = new object();' instance to the Func delegate? Could that be avoided?

Comment: I don't think we will add `this.` implicitly as you suggest. We'd have to detect if you already have an expression like `@this.DoSomething()` and skip that case. Seems like too much trouble for not that much gain. Ideally we will just add those methods to the `WebPageBase` class itself so that they are always available.

Comment: Regarding the `_o = new object()` it's because razor inline templates are actually `Func<object, HelperResult>` so you need to pass something in. I could pass in `null` but because of the way things work the inline template has access to the `item` lambda parameter so someone might try to do something with it and they would get a NullRefException. If you don't touch `item` then it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

To override a section:

```
@section Footer {
    <div>Put your overriden content here</div>
}
```

Comment: I will clarify my question a little more.